# How to get the details from wsdl page

Tags: php, web-services

I have been using the http://www.mobilefish.com/services/web_service/countries.php?wsdl file to get the country geographic details. But i have been failing in achieving it by nusoap. Plz advise me on this regard

```
<?php
require_once('ws/lib/nusoap.php'); //including the file 

$client = new nusoap_client('http://www.mobilefish.com/services/web_service/countries.php?wsdl');

$geo = $client->call('countryInfoByIana',  //calling the method of server object and 
              array('ianacode' => 'us'));

              var_dump($geo);
?>
```

The help guide is http://www.mobilefish.com/tutorials/web_service/web_service_quickguide_countries.html page. plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$client = new nusoap_client('http://www.mobilefish.com/services/web_service/countries.php?wsdl',true);
```

set second parameter as true to make wsdl client

Comment: Sorry, MMT still getting problem. Every thing looks fine. but its ducking me crazy.

Comment: are you getting any exception?